# Flutter: How to make draggable bottom sheet with fixed draggable triggering

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, singlechildscrollview

i want to make something like below:

initial state of the bottom sheet

[image: initial bottom sheet],

when dragging upward the bottomsheet

[image: bottom sheet on dragging]

**Expected behavior**
when i drag upward the bottomsheet, the content will be displayed like the second picture, and when the sheet reach the max heigh provided, only the list behind the title will be scrollable but the title and the white box above the title will be fixed at their place.

this how i set the modal sheet:

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
          initialChildSize: 0.05,
          minChildSize: 0.05,
          maxChildSize: 0.8,
          builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController){
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: scrollController,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        spreadRadius: 2,
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                      ),
                    ]
                  ),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            width: WidgetScreen.width(context, 70),
                            height: 7,
                          )
                        )
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const Text('My cars'),
                          IconButton(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            focusColor: Colors.red,
                            splashRadius: 20,
                            onPressed: (){}, 
                            icon: const Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.add,
                              size: 15,
                            )
                          )
                        ]
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          controller: scrollController,
                          itemCount: 25,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ]
                  ),
                ),
              )
            );
          }
        )
```

the `SingleChildScrollView` allow me to make the `DraggableScrollableSheet` work fine cause the child of this one must be a list to have the drag behavior work.

**What i got**

when the sheet reach the max height provided, if i scroll inside the list, i got what i want, but if i scroll from the title bloc all the content is scrolling like bellow

[image: behavior i got]

**NB**
I tried to find a package or using the modal sheet of flutter but all of them need an external trigger to display the bottom sheet like on click on something but i don't want it to behave this way.

**PS**
the `WidgetScreen.width(context, 70)` is some helper that i created so just replace it with some int value

Comment: Did you try https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_bottom_sheet or this https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_bottom_sheet

Comment: this one work well:  pub.dev/packages/expandable_bottom_sheet
is there a way to make the same without using this package?

Comment: You either fork the package and do your own custom changes or you just look inside the package code and look how they implemented it, so you can do it yourself ^^

Comment: it's what i did but i didn't make custom yet xD there are to much info